# Python List to Javascript Observable Array

Tags: javascript, python, list, flask, knockout.js

So I am implementing an API through Python Flask. My code structure is something like the following:

```
src/
|--> main.py
|--> api/
|     |--> users.py
|--> static/
      |--> index.html
```

Inside `users.py` I have a list called `user_list`. The thing is I want to perform some operations with that list, for which I want to make it an Observable Array to and handle it in `index.html`. Speaking roughly, I do not know how to send that list from `users.py` to `index.html` through `main.py` (which handles the whole API).

I am really lost on how to do this, as I do not understand JavaScript's Observable Arrays at all.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have observable arrays. Knockout.js [does](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

Comment: Ok, that sums up pretty well my knowledge about it :)

Comment: you would have to put list in html - you could use `render_template()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-populate an observable array, pass an array to the `ko.observableArray` function. To pass an array from Flask code through the template to JavaScript, use Flask's `tojson` filter. Thus, in the template:

```
<script>
  const userList = ko.observableArray({{ user_list | tojson }});
</script>
```

It is impossible to do this in a static file, for obvious reasons (you want some dynamic content injected into it). An alternative that *would* work with a static `index.html` would be to populate your observable array via AJAX, but since you provided no code, it is hard to tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: I have a template which uses AJAX, so I guess I should use it, but I honestly don't understand how to make ```index.html``` know that I am referring to ```users.py->user_list```